# How do you bake procedural normals correctly? The final normal map puts a normal value on everything

Tags: texture-baking, normal-map

File: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RFVXni_Clj5TYH5lkj8hXbAvwPWN6zbl/view?usp=sharing

Very basic problem I have. I want to use procedural noise to create a normal map. But I get normal values where it should be unaffected. The only normal data we should see is from the procedural pattern.[image][image][image]

Comment: Your link is private. You need to make your blend file public so we can access it.

Comment: I think the Color Space of the baked normal map is not correct. But not sure because I don't know how you baked it.

Comment: it's no longer private

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/caBlM.jpg <= You can bake it if you select the UV Map *BakeWrangler-Eyes* & plug the input for the *Bump* node into a *Displacement* node. But the *Scale* slot works kinda different & the result is always a "ring" in the center of the eye in the baked normal map. So I've added these 3 math nodes to smooth it out.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYDsJ.jpg <= The baked normal map looks good but if you use it then the result still looks different. I don't know why. The calculated normals (output of the *Normal Map*  node) are different. Check it with the NodeWrangler add-on.

Comment: @Blunder what scale? And are you basically saying that using displacement and then baking a low poly to high poly would work better? Not sure how to use displacement to create a normal map otherwise.

Comment: *Scale* is one input slot of the *Displacement* node (see image above). It's similar to the *Strength* input slot of the *Bump* node. My plan was to redirect both inputs (*Height+Strength*) of the *Bump* node to the *Displacement* node. But it doesn't work 1:1. To be clear, the displacement is not related to a high-poly to low-poly bake. You just use the low-poly model + the *Displacement* node for the *Displacement* input of the *Material Output* node. This is needed to bake the normal input that you've created procedurally.

Comment: I've cleaned up my mess, have a look here ;-) https://pasteall.org/blend/11b83ab1355e487e9e83c8f8d0604986

Comment: So, I think I can answer this myself now. Your node setup is a bit complex. I just came up with a simplified node solution. For some reason creating a gradient from black to white and then multiplying by .0005 makes the range perfect for the height input while a black and white pattern can go into the scale input (or you could swap height and scale, same result). You get a smooth fade from neutral to high/low on the normal map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Blunder.

[image]

Basically, use displacement instead of normal. Disconnect the normal input of the Principled BSDF.

1. Create a displacement node.
2. Plug your black and white bump mask into height of displacement node.
3. Plug displacement output into material output displacement.
4. Set displacement scale value to .001
5. Optional: Make a black and white gradient using color ramp, multiply its output with your mask.